# Add to basket ecommerce function without using GTM. Will the following act as expected?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've been tasked with hard-coding enhanced ecommerce tracking to a website (without the use of any tag management). The task is to simple include 'add to basket'.

It's expected that I define the data fields with some variables, rather than a string.

So, given [this web page](http://uk.oakley.com/en/mens/new-arrivals/new-sunglasses/fives-squared-prizm-shallow-water-polarized/product/W0OO9238PZSW/?skuCode=OO9238-18&categoryCode=m0101), would the following script pull the relevant data I'm expecting? (SKU, Product name, price and quantity selected)

```js
// Called when a product is added to a shopping cart. 
function addToCart(product) {    
  ga('ec:addProduct', {       
     'id': document.getElementsByClassName(‘sku’).text,        
     'name’:  document.getElementsByClassName('pdHero-name h4’).text,       
     'price’:  document.getElementById('salePrice').text,       
     'quantity’:  document.getElementByClassName(‘oakley-custom-selectInner’).text     
     });    
  ga('ec:setAction', 'add');    
  ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add to cart');     // Send data using an event.  
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting... I was really struggling to get it to show up neatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your snippets above return errors when I run them on the page, so I would make the stab that they do not currently work.

The easiest way to confirm is to open the webpage in your web browser, and then try running the snippets in a javascript console (e.g. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> in Chrome for Mac).

If you can, it is almost certainly better to scrape by `id` or by `name`, because these are less likely to change for frivolous reasons - `class` is primarily for style and so it is very likely to change when the page style does.

Class name and name refer to different parts of the html element:

```
<div class="bold" name="first" id="firstId">here is some value</div>
<div class="bold" name="second" id="secondId">here is a second value</div>
```

- `getElementsByClassName('bold')` checks for `class=`, and would return *both* of the divs above in a list
- `getElementsByName('first')` checks for `name=`, and would return only the first (but in a list, because there theoretically *could* be more than one element with that name)
- `getElementById('secondId')` checks for `id=`, and would return only the second.

In the case of the first two functions, you'll always need to access the first element before accessing any other properties, e.g. `getElementsByName('first')[0].innerText`, but note this will raise an exception if there are *no* elements in the page with that name.

Another point of caution: it looks like a bunch of the quotes in your code block have been replaced by smart-quotes, which will not work if you use them in your real code (e.g. `‘` or `’` instead of `'`). If you're working on a Mac I would recommend [turning off smart quotes](http://www.iclarified.com/38772/how-to-disable-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x-mavericks) altogether.

Going deeper into the question is probably too specific to be useful for Stack Overflow, but if you have any particular difficulty with a field that might be useful to post as a separate question.